# How to download a ZIp file from a URl and store them as Zip file only

Tags: java, zip, download

I have a url like below

```
  http://blah.com/download.zip
```

I want a java code to download this Zip file from the URL and save it in my server directory as ZIP file  only . I would also like to know what is the most effecient way to do this.

Comment: Ya i am using InputStream stream= connection.getInputStream(); but looks like he is making some mistake because the same file downloaded by Firefox shows more data compared to what it shows by my java code.

Answer (score 2):

First, your URL is *not* `http:\\blah.com\download.zip`. It is `http://blah.com/download.zip`.

Second, it is simple. You have to perform HTTP GET request, take the stream and copy it to `FileOutputStream`. Here is the code sample.

```
URL url = new URL("http://blah.com/download.zip");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("download.zip");
copy(in, out, 1024);
out.close();


  public static void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];
    int n = input.read(buf);
    while (n >= 0) {
      output.write(buf, 0, n);
      n = input.read(buf);
    }
    output.flush();
  }
```

Comment: probably a typo, `bytesRead` should be `n`